# Abstract error when changing TStringList to TStrings

Tags: delphi

Ok this is becoming quite silly...

It's the second time (the first time was 30min before, on a function to get directory tree)  I ever see the error "Abstract error", and really can't tell why would it happen.

I had this function, to list all of the hard drives:

```
function TForm2.GetDriveList:TStringList;
 var
    s:string;
    i:integer;
    DriveStr:array[1..255] of char;
    t:integer;
  begin
    GetLogicalDriveStrings(255,@DriveStr);
    result:=TStringList.create;
    i:=1;
    repeat
      s:='';
      while (i<=255) and (DriveStr[i]<>#00) do
      begin
        s:=s+char(drivestr[i]);
        inc(i);
      end;
      inc(i); {step over #00}
      t:=getdrivetype(Pchar(s));
      if (length(s)>0) and (t=DRIVE_FIXED)

        then result.add(s);
    until length(s)=0;

 end;
```

Now, I changed the TStringList to TStrings, and I get this Abstract error when trying to call it;

I also tried to change it to procedure, as

```
procedure TFrom2.GetDriveList(List: TStrings);
```

removing the result from the code, and having List.Add(s) at the end;

This (function to procedure) somehow solved the issue in my first case, but doesn't on this one.

My questions are:
What is wrong in the code above, and why is TStrings not accepted...?

and: what the heck are these abstract errors, how to identify them, since they appear (by debug inspection) on the very end of the function/procedure, after it is basically already done?

Comment: You are not supposed to **instantiate** `TStrings`. Please consult the fine documentation.

Comment: What does this mean? Instantiate...?
I get the same error if I try to assign the StringList result to a variable of type TStrings...  Why does it work with Listbox1.Items.Assign, where Items are TStrings...?

Comment: That happens because `TListBox.Items` isn't `TStrings` internally, but this is completely different story.

Comment: Ok, got it now. From @David's answer I see what you both mean...

Comment: Oh, by the way, line containing `TStrings.Create` should cause compiler to spew a plenty of warnings. Its a good idea to attend and resolve then.

Comment: I would prefer making it procedure rather than function returning a new instance of a string list. Some time ago I wrote a similar function for listing drives by type (for one installer) and today I've made a review of that code and translated it into Delphi. [`Here it is`](http://pastebin.com/9Nkp3THn) if you want to take a look.

Comment: @TLama Thanks! That looks nice. I'll have to try it, although right now the code above works as needed too so...  But good to have another/better option :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`TStrings`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStrings) is an abstract base class. It must not be instantiated. It exists to be a common base class for concrete derived classes. Like `TStringList` for one, like the `TStrings` derived classes exposed by `TMemo`, `TListBox` and so on. The documentation says:

> TStrings is the base class for objects that represent a list of strings.
>
> Derive a class from TStrings to store and manipulate a list of strings. TStrings contains abstract or, in C++ terminology, pure virtual methods and should not be directly instantiated.

The rule is stated clearly. Do not instantiate `TStrings`.

An abstract error is the runtime error that arises when you call an abstract method. An abstract method is a virtual method that has no implementation. Abstract methods cannot be called. This is why abstract classes should not be instantiated.

If you are not familiar with what an abstract method is then you need to go back to the documentation and brush up your knowledge. Start here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Methods#Virtual_and_Dynamic_Methods

Comment: Ok. So said, never use TStrings type. Acknowledged... Didn't know that...  man, that Delphi is funny.. :)

Comment: No. You can use TStrings. For instance as a parameter type so to be compatible with any descendent. Just don't instantiate it. Just like TStream.

Comment: Yeah, I got that I can still pass it as a parameter, but I can't declare it otherwise...?

Comment: You can declare a variable to be of type TStrings and assign an instance of a derived class. You just must not instantiate TStrings. The only thing you cannot do is TStrings.Create.

Comment: @LDFreak Perhaps you simply do not understand the meaning of the word `instantiate`. Simply put, it's when you create an `instance`, hence the terminology similarity.

Comment: It's not about TStrings. It's about declaring classes that contain methods tagged as "virtual abstract". You add "abstract" if you don't want the class to be instantiated -- meaning you want users of that class to never use it directly, but to always derive another class from it. TStringList is derived from TStrings. Interfaces are semantically equivalent to abstract base classes, only they cannot contain data members. You never create an instance of an Interface. Abstract base classes are the same; you define a pattern of methods that you want users of the class to implement.

Comment: @David Terminology here is really important. Unfortunately "use it directly" is imprecise. You mean "instantiate".

Comment: You're correct, but since the OP seems to not understand that term, I chose to "clarify" the phrase another way. :)